# How to creat menu multi-levels with sub-menu with php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have a dynamic menu that feeds from a table using php and mysql.

My table looks like this:

```
| id |   name    |    group   |
|----|-----------|------------|
|  1 | section 1 |   group 1  |
|  2 | section 2 |   group 2  |
|  4 |  group 1  | section 21 |
|  5 |  group 2  | section 22 |
```

I can do a query to get and display unique sec_group values but can't figure out a way to include sec_name into each sec_group

```
//Query by unique sec_group
$qry_secs="SELECT DISTINCT sec_group FROM tbl_user_sec ORDER BY sec_id ASC";
$result_secs = mysql_query($qry_secs);

//echo values
while ($row_secs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_secs)){
    echo `<ul><li><a href="#">'.$row_secs['sec_group'].'</a></li></ul>`';
}
```

Eventually, the HTML should like the code below.

```
|---- section 1
   |---- group 1
      |---- section 21

|---- section 2
   |---- group 2
      |---- section 22
```

Comment: Don't use the _deprecated and insecure_ `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Your table is a little confusing, Is the "name" column pulled from the "sec_id" column in your table? And the "group" pulled from the "sec_group" column? In any case, it would help if you could modify your table, and include a level number. The first 2 entries would be level 1, and the 3rd and 4th would be level 2. Then, when you query the table, you can query all the level 1s first, then level 2s, then build your menu from the results.